# Simple example of transparent proxy with Cisco IOS and Squid

Tags: cisco, proxy, squid, cache, transparent-proxy

Does anyone have a simple example with Cisco IOS and Squid whereby a Cisco router intercepts traffic and redirects it to an adjacent Squid 3 cache?  Is there a way to do this for only certain requests (e.g. .zip, .rar, etc ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this: [Transparent Squid with WCCP](http://www.digitalnerds.net/linux/transparent-squid-with-wccp/)?